# How to read spring boot property file in service class method called by unit test

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have spring boot application. I want to write some unit test for methods in service class.
I can load Environment variable and get properties in unit test class but can't do it in service class. Environment in service class is always null when reaching it from unit tests. It work when reaching it from application.

**SomethingServiceTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@TestPropertySource(value = "/application.properties")
public class SomethingServiceTest {

     private ISomethingService m_SomethingService;

     @PostConstruct
     public void setup() {
        m_SomethingService = new SomethingService();
        m_SomethingService.setSomethingRepository(somethingRepository);
        // somethingRepository is mocked class, probably not important
     }

    @Test
    public void test_somethingMethod() {
         System.out.println(env.getProperty("some.property"));
         //env here is full and i get wanted property
         m_uploadService.doSomething();
    }
```

**ISomethingService.java**

```
public interface ISomethingService {
    doSomething();
}
```

**SomethingService.java**

```
@Service
public class SomethingService implements ISomethingService {

    @Value("${some.property}")
    private String someProperty;

    private ISomethingRepository somethingRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ISomethingRepository getSomethingRepository() {
        return somethingRepository;
    }

    public void setSomethingRepository(ISomethingRepository p_somethingRepository) {
        somethingRepository = p_somethingRepository;
    }

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public String doSomething(){
        System.out.println(env.getProperty("some.property"));
        //env is null here
        return someProperty;
    }
}
```